# Is FB.ui send dialog available on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to implement send dialog using FB.ui.  Is it possible?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 4):

```
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
    message: 'msg',
    name: 'name',
    link: 'your link',
    picture: 'your pic',
    caption: 'caption',
    description: 'desc',
    display: 'touch' // TAKE NOTE
});
```

Comment: where's the explanation? ...it's not the same as send.
It still says device unsupported for me.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/ setting the display mode = "touch" should work on iOS.

Comment: The docs say that display=touch does not work on the send dialog:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: "`Platform Dialogs are all built to seamlessly run in a variety of display contexts on both the web and mobile web. If you're invoking a Dialog using the JS, iOS or Android SDKs, the display mode will be automatically chosen for you based on the platform and the device being used by the user. However, you can force a particular display mode by setting the display parameter to one of the following values:`"

Comment: `touch: For use on smartphones, mobile devices and small tablets (such as those with screens under 7 inches).`

Comment: This is quotes from the current page.  It still seems to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
    message: 'msg',
    name: 'name',
    link: 'your link',
    picture: 'your pic',
    caption: 'caption',
    description: 'desc',
    display: 'touch' // TAKE NOTE
});
```